# I am getting such Kind Of Problem : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, mongodb, fetch

I am using react js and using mongo db. i am trying to get data by fetch. but i get this type of error : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  const url = `http://localhost:5000/product/${id}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setProduct(data));
}, [id]);
```

Comment: `fetch` resolves even if the status code is not a success code. It sounds like the response is an error with an empty body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in useEffect is correct the reason you may be getting this error is because of

1. There is no JSON data from the backend
2. Maybe the JSON you received is not proper JSON

you can confirm this by replacing res.json() with res.text() and then console.log it

Comment: I made a backend server and insert data manually, that's why data were not in a JSON format. I Delete all data and keep it in JSON  format.

Answer (score 0):

You should include a `.catch()` call in your chain of method calls off the `fetch`, so that you can handle errors or malformed input from your API. The error is saying it's "uncaught" because there is no `catch` clause.

i.e.

```js
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setProduct(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error("Something went wrong: ", error))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. I made a backend server and insert data manually, that's why data were not in a JSON format in the database. I Delete all data from the database and keep it in JSON format.